# How can I define a greedy macro?

Tags: macros, expl3, l3keys

I have a feeling this is a duplicate somewhere, but how can I ensure that TeX will keep scanning until `\relax` or something similar?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

Plain:

\def\test#1/#2/#3{
  year:#1   \newline
  month:#2  \newline
  day:#3    \newline
}
\test 01/02/03

\bigskip

Expl3:

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \test:w #1/#2/#3 {
  year:#1   \newline
  month:#2  \newline
  day:#3    \newline
}

\test:w 01/02/03
\ExplSyntaxOff

\bigskip

Keys:

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { test } {
  date .code:n = { \test:w #1 },
  title .code:n = { title: #1 \newline},
}

\keys_set:nn {test} { title = hello, date = 15/16/17, title = hi}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I realize that I could introduce some token—perhaps the quark `\q_stop`—to the `l3keys` `.code:n` usage to terminate it 'normally'. Is there a way to go about doing this without such an introduction?

Comment: Note: According to a [chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16129903#16129903) backed by `texdoc expl3`, it is correct to say `\test:www` rather than `test:w`.

Comment: I don't know about ‘correct’ — in this particular case using `\test:www 01/02/03 <whatever>` sort of does imply that the three numbers match up with the three args, so it's probably a good idea. In other cases where you don't get this nice symmetry, just using `w` would be fine. I even started using `q` for ‘delimited by quark’ arguments, but the other team members didn't seem to like it `:)`

Comment: @WillRobertson I for one think using `q` is a fine idea.  The main point behind both of those argspecs, I think, is to encourage the reader to go back and RTFM `:)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An argument is either delimited or undelimited; in the latter case only the first token or braced group is taken as the argument. Your `\test:w` macro has an undelimited third argument; delimit also the third argument and add the final delimiter in the `.code:n` part.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \test:www #1 / #2 / #3 \q_stop {
  year:#1   \newline
  month:#2  \newline
  day:#3    \newline
}

\test:w 01/02/03 \q_stop
\ExplSyntaxOff

\bigskip

Keys:

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { test } {
  date .code:n = { \test:www #1 \q_stop },
  title .code:n = { title: #1 \newline},
}

\keys_set:nn {test} { title = hello, date = 15/16/17, title = hi}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Possibly better code that doesn't use delimited arguments explicitly. Less efficient, perhaps, but clearer. You can add several checks that the date is legal; wrong input with `\test:www` would result in an unscrutable error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{ m }
 {
  \keys_set:nn { sean/test } { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \sean_test:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__sean_date_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__sean_date_seq == 3 }
   {
    year: ~\seq_item:Nn \l__sean_date_seq { 1 } \newline
    month:~\seq_item:Nn \l__sean_date_seq { 2 } \newline
    day:  ~\seq_item:Nn \l__sean_date_seq { 3 } \newline
   }
   {
    BAD~DATE!
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \sean_test:nn { V }

\keys_define:nn { sean/test }
 {
  date-delimiter .tl_set:N = \l_sean_date_delimiter_tl,
  date-delimiter .initial:n = { / },
  date .code:n = { \sean_test:Vn \l_sean_date_delimiter_tl { #1 } },
  title .code:n = { title: ~ #1 \newline },
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\test{ title = hello, date = 15/16/17, title = hi }

\bigskip

\test{ title = hi, date-delimiter = - , date = 01-02-03 }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I ended up doing—this is the simplest way, but is there another that would work? (I'm perfectly okay using the quark solution—that's what it was meant for—but I'm curious :)

Comment: @SeanAllred No you can't; I added some words at the beginning.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what you need, perhaps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

Plain:

\def\test#1/#2/#3 {
  year:#1   \newline
  month:#2  \newline
  day:#3    \newline
}
\test 01/02/03

\bigskip

Expl3:

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \test:w #1/#2/#3~{
  year:#1   \newline
  month:#2  \newline
  day:#3    \newline
}

\test:w 01/02/03~
\ExplSyntaxOff

\bigskip

Keys:

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { test } {
  date .code:n = { \test:w #1~ },
  title .code:n = { title: #1 \newline},
}

\keys_set:nn {test} { title = hello, date = 15/16/17, title = hi}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looking at egreg's answer, this is the general solution strategy (to delimit the argument) but note that quarks were introduced in `expl3` for just this very purpose :) it doesn't need a space (even though we can both see that the space will never go to the input stream).

Comment: @SeanAllred quarks predated expl3 (and latex2e for that matter:-) yes I used a space as that's the natural terminator for your non expl3 \test example as it just picks up the end of line.

Comment: I had no idea—and yes, you're definitely right that a space is the natural terminator when we are talking plain TeX.